# Single unit testing for a single test case?

Tags: unit-tests, testcase

Do you first create a test case and then you create a unit test?

Is single unit testing for a single test case and not many unit testing for a single test case?

Comment: Why do you have this question? What is the context of your confusion?

Comment: I understand that you need to have a test case in relation to integration or GUI test but how is it in relation to unit test?

Comment: Why do you need a test-cases for an integration or GUI test? Who is telling you that and where? In my current team all the automate tests are THE test-cases. They have no relation to any other data or test-management tool. If you NEED to have a relation create it, if you dont then dont. https://martinfowler.com/bliki/Yagni.html

Comment: Maybe you can describe this "relation" with more context. We might be able to give a better answer.

Comment: Unit testing is only a methodolody. Before creating a method you need to have a purpose and goal. The next phase is to find a correct method that should achieve the goal and purpose.

Answer (score 0):

The unit-test is the test-case, but for a really small part functionality in the source-code. Unit-test are always linked to a (public) method (of a class), not a more general high-level test-case.

Although in [TDD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development) you should start with a failing higher level integration or end2end test. For which you start building functionality based on unit-tests. In this case you would start with a failing e2e test, then write a failing unit-test, write some code, write a failing unit-test, write some code, repeat until e2e test succeeds.

More info:

> A unit is the smallest testable part of software. It usually has one
>   or a few inputs and usually a single output.
>
> http://softwaretestingfundamentals.com/unit-testing/

Goal:

> The goal of unit testing is to isolate each part of the program and
>   show that the individual parts are correct. A unit test provides a
>   strict, written contract that the piece of code must satisfy.
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing